# Calling abort() on MacOS results in trap, but no core dump is produced

Tags: c, macos, gcc, clang, abort

I am studying Linux system programming and I was trying out the `abort()` function. The book I am studying from makes note that calling `abort()` results in writing file `core` file prior to exiting the process and writing `Abort (core dumped)` to stdout (I also confirmed this output in some of the abort-related question on SO). However, from this simple program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Starting process %d\n", getpid());

    abort();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output

```
Starting process 2753
Abort trap: 6
```

and no file is produced. I cannot understand why. Permissions for the file are `0777`. Any ideas of why this happens?

P.S.: I am using macOS Mojave, compiler is gcc, or so I think. It might be clang tho... This is the output of `gcc -v`:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

however, the output of `which gcc` is `/usr/bin/gcc`.

Comment: As far as I know, macos doesn't write core dumps like linux does. I'm not 100% on that though.

Comment: @Qix Thanks a lot, I guess it has to be something like this but I didn't find anything online.

Comment: The core dump is kind of a cherry-on-top kind of thing, and (personally) I have never used them. Most of the time, you're going to be in lldb (clang) or gdb (gcc) to debug aborts. If you boot up lldb or gdb and run your abort test, the debugger will break at the abort statement so you can see why it's aborting.

Comment: Technically, `abort` doesn't print anything. The message in question (`Abort (core dumped)`) is printed by the parent process (`bash`).

Comment: @Qix Yeah, I know that. I am used to gdb but I wanted to see the core dump just out of curiosity.

Comment: @ikegami Indeed, that is true.

Comment: I don't know if this applies to your OS, but have you seen [this](https://jvns.ca/blog/2018/04/28/debugging-a-segfault-on-linux/)? In particular, it seems the core dump size soft limit my processes get by default is 0 for me, which is (at least one reason) why I don't get core dumps

Comment: @ikegami Running `ulimit -c unlimited` helped and on macOS cores get dumped to `/core/core.PID` where `PID` is the pid of process in question. For further reference if someone will need it.